# C# Quine Problem

Tags: c#, quine

I am trying to understand how this piece of self-replicating code works (found [here](http://safalra.com/programming/c-sharp/quines/)), but the problem is I can't get it to run **as-is**:

```
class c {
    static void Main(){

        string s = "class c{{static void Main(){{string s={0}{10};System.Console.Write(s,(char)34,s);}}}}";

        System.Console.Write(s,(char)34,s); //<<-- exception on this line

    }
}
```

It's throwing an exception on writeline: **Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.**

Can someone help - in particular about the formatting option {0}{10}?

I got it working like this (see below) but it's longer than the original - I am curious how the original could have worked as-is in the 1st place:

```
class c {
    static void Main(){

        string s = "class c{{static void Main(){{string s={0}{1}{2};System.Console.Write(s,(char)34,s,(char)34);}}}}";

        System.Console.Write(s,(char)34,s,(char)34);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think there is a pair of braces missing - instead of `{10}` it should read `{1}{0}`.

```
class c {
    static void Main(){

        string s = "class c{{static void Main(){{string s={0}{1}{0};System.Console.Write(s,(char)34,s);}}}}";

        System.Console.Write(s,(char)34,s); //<<-- exception on this line

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Could the original work with?

```
s={0}{1}{0}
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the original was supposed to look like this:

```
class c {
  static void Main() {
    string s = "class c{{static void Main(){{string s={0}{1}{0};System.Console.Write(s,(char)34,s);}}}}";
    System.Console.Write(s, (char)34, s);
  }
}
```

I.e. the `{0}{10}` should just be changed to `{0}{1}{0}`.

The `{0}` in the format string is used to put the quotation marks before and after the string.