# Is the reflection namespace a building block for writing a quine in C#?

Tags: c#, system.reflection, quine

Do I need to use reflection to write a quine program for C#?
I read elsewhere - [quine](http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/quine.html) that opening the source file from disk is "cheating"
So I guess using .net reflector and/or opening the source file using System.IO is a hack.

Are there other ways other than using Reflection that I should be considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need reflection or anything else to make a quine, just a little string manipluation and some time.

```
using System;      
class Q      
{   
    static void Main()    
    {
        string s = "using System;class Q{2}static void Main(){2}string s ={1}{0}{1};
        Console.Write(string.Format(s, s, (char)34, (char)123, (char)125));{3}{3}";             
        Console.Write(string.Format(s, s, (char)34, (char)123, (char)125));          
    }   
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762984/c-quine-problem) is another stack overflow question with a similar theme.
The above quine is from [here](http://www.yetanotherdeveloper.com/post/2008/01/20/My-Quine.aspx).